# Question regarding "independent variables" term in regression analysis definition

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Definition:

Regression analysis is used for explaining or modeling the relationship between a single variable Y, called
the response, output or dependent variable, and one or more predictor, input, independent or explanatory
variables, X1 .... Xp.

from this book https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf

What does independent variables mean in the definition?

Considering Xs to be random variables,does it mean that P(Xi|Xj) = P(Xi). BUt this would be very constrainted for anyone trying to use regression analysis as inputs tend to be dependent in most of the cases.

Comment: "Independent variable" is just one of the many names used for the right-hand side variables (just re-read the quoted passage!). The term is meant to illustrate that the modeled dependence goes from right to left (the value of Y "depends" on the value of the Xs). No, the Xs are not assumed to be pairwise independent.

Comment: can someone close this question...i dont have enough rep to do that i guess

Comment: You can delete your own question that doesn't have an upvoted answer. Voting to close etc. not needed here. You should see a box for doing that.

Comment: Many threads on this site deal with independent variables.  I will redirect this thread to the (current) top hit on a [search for "independent variable"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=independent+variable).